# $\sin(1/x)$ is not BV.

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

I have to prove that 
$$
 \begin{cases} 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      \sin(1/x) & x\in \Big(0,\frac{2}{\pi}\Big] \\
      0 & x=0
    \end{array}
\end{cases}
$$
is not of bounded variation. I am unable to figure out the partition of this, so please provide me any partition s.t. it is not of BV.

Comment: What are the extrema of the function? What's the value they assume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Consider $x_k = [\pi(k + 1/2)]^{-1}$ for $k = 0, 1 \ldots, n$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left| \sin(1/x_k) - \sin(1/x_{k-1})\right| = \cdots$$

Comment: Thanks! Now I can do this. But could you please tell me the idea that how can I figure it out.

Comment: What is the definition of variation of a function with respect to a partition? I provided more than sufficient hint -  so you need to do some of the work.

Comment: No I am not asking the rest of the stuff, I was asking that how do you get this partition. I want idea. I have already done that problem after getting the partition from you.

Comment: These are the points where $\sin(1/x)$ alternately has a maximum +1 and minimum -1.